Where does dnf-5 (Fedora 41) keep its transaction history?
Every night, my Fedora systems run a crontab script that does dnf update -y.
It is actually a small Perl script that also tries to run rkhunter --propupd if necessary.
I used to be able to check the timestamp on /var/lib/dnf/history.sqlite-wal to see if any modules had been updated, but since I did the version-upgrade to F41, none of the files in var/lib/dnf/ appear to have been touched.
Where has the history database moved to?

/usr/lib/sysimage/libdnf5/transaction_history.sqlite (see man dnf, under "FILES", "System State")
Anyway, what you do kind of sounds like a hack, doesn't it?  You could either

run dnf check-upgrade || echo "updates available" to check for availability of upgrades before actually doing the dnf update, or you could
run dnf history list --reverse | tail -n1 and check whether that string is actually new.


I am not sure that your proposal for dnf check-upgrade works as described. In my quick and superficial test, I see exit status ($?) equal to 0 (true)  even when there is "Nothing to do".

it's 0 exactly when there's nothing to do. Check the man page!
